# How to include or add extarnal other.js file in my.js file without node js

Tags: javascript

I want to add an external javascript file in another javascript file. For example my file name is info.js, now I want to include "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/axios/dist/axios.min.js" in my info.js file.
I don't want to use this CND  `<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>` in my html file like this.

I did the following code, which adds the CDN to the html file, but it's not working.

```
function include(file) {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = file;
     document.getElementsByTagName('script').item(0).before(script);
    }
    /* Include Many js files */
   include('https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/axios/dist/axios.min.js');
```

Actually I am not good at English. I hope you understand my problem. Have any solution for me?

Thanks

Comment: visit that address in your browser, `ctrl + a`, `ctrl + c` open your info.js file, `ctrl + v`  ?

Comment: Can't you just add 2 separate `<script>` tags? If not, check [jQuery getscript](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/)

Comment: just download that .js file into your own site's source tree alongside info.js and do `<script src="axios.min.js">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dynamically create a `script` element and set its `src` attribute to the axios library URL. Then it will append the script element to the head of the document.
You can then use the `axios` library as usual in your `info.js` file.

```
// Create a script element
var script = document.createElement('script');
// Set the src attribute to the external library URL with a cache-busting parameter
script.src = 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/axios/dist/axios.min.js?' + Date.now();
// Append the script element to the head of the document
document.head.appendChild(script);
```

Comment: Its working only after reloading the page, its not work for first visitor.

Comment: You can add a cache-busting parameter to the script URL to solve the problem, like a timestamp or a random number.
The code is edited (Added the time stamp to the script URL) try it :)

Comment: Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: axios is not defined
    <anonymous> http://localhost/new/pixel/index.js:48
    promise callback* http://localhost/new/pixel/index.js:40
    promise callback* http://localhost/new/pixel/index.js:33